# A position of a column in order grid was changed.

Tags: adminhtml

I'm not sure why the multi check button are fixed beside the last element. 
Do you know why ? And how to move it? It hasn't moved by drag and drop comparing to other components!

FYI, i had experienced that i inserted the custom module to bring customer company to order grid like this : 
https://github.com/meezin/Magento2.1.X_AddCompanyColumnToSalesOrderGrid

Thank you

[image]